# .NET Web API Unit Test for model with DbGeography System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a working ASP NET Web APIs, some of which are using Spatial Data Types using DbGeography. I added this line to the startup code to make it work here.
`SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));`

I have a unit testing project, which is referencing the project mentioned above. When trying to run a test that calls a method that uses DbGeograohy, I get the error "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'".

This error appeared previously in the Web API project, and I solved by adding the line above to the startup class, which basically loads the native Windows library.

I want to learn if it's possible to have a "Startup" class for the tests, where the library would be loaded before executing them.

Cheers :)

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete and would require too many questions to clarify what is being asked. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing us to better understand what is being asked.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I just edited the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Is this meant to be an isolated unit test or an end to end integration test? `Server.MapPath("~/bin")` wont be available during isolated unit tests as it will be directly tied to IIS or what ever is hosting the service.

Comment: It's an isolated unit test unfortunately, and I don't really need to use the code above in the test since I'm doing it locally, I can just hard code the  DLL file's path if that's the problem.

Comment: Then it appears that your code is tightly coupled to 3rd part resources that are not available when testing your code in isolation. consider reviewing your current design to address the tight coupling.

Comment: encapsulate the `Server.MapPath` behind an abstraction that can be mocked when testing to allow more flexibility in providing the path.